# Create sub controller without route in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm building a chat app with ember.js(I'm very new to it) that has the following specifics:

- Every user have multiple threads each one with only two users involved
- I need to display the thread and the messages in a "facebook" manner with the list of threads aside and the messages right of it
- Every message have a read state that I need to work with
- The app works with an url pattern like `/:thread_id`

Giving theese, I've already setted up an app 
https://gist.github.com/Fed03/33da4a7c28c792af23cf (I've merged the various js file for sake of your readability) but the problem rises on the specific message state.
From what I understand about ember, evrything "needs" a route in order to proxy things, but if you look at the code and at the specifics a don't need a `message` route but I'd need a `MessageController` to manage the single message states.

Obviously I'm doing something very wrong with the architecture of this app, so if someone cuold give me some advices would be great!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a [{{render}} helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-render-code-helper).

Instead of rendering each model in the threads template, pass the model to a `{{render}}` and have it handle displaying the message and it'll have it's own controller.

You'll need to create a seperate template for the msg, like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="message">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="well">
             <div class="message-header">
                 <h5>{{user.fullname}}</h5>
             </div>
                 {{body}}
                 {{isRead msg}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

And then change your thread template to this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="thread">
    {{#each msg in model.messages}}
        {{render 'message' msg}}
    {{/each}}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                {{textarea value=message rows="3" class="form-control" data-thread=model}}
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" {{action 'send' model}}>
                        Submit
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Then each `msg` will have it's own instance of `MessageController` and you can use it to handle it's state.

Comment: this dosn't answer my question on how to manage states and variables for every single message without a message route/controller